# Windows 7 administrator security bypassed?

Tags: windows-7, security, passwords, user-accounts, login

I've an old system at home in which I've installed Windows 7 Professional. I use it seldom, although it contains important data and software for my use. I've created two accounts in it- one is mine, that's default, and has administrative rights, and other for my younger brother (a guest account).
My main account (i.e., administrator) is protected by a password, thus if my brother wants to install any piece of software such as games, etc., it would require my permission.

But from sometime, I am noticing that every time I log in to my account, Windows doesn't prompt password for log in! Besides, new games and software are installed in it, which would, for sure require 'Administrative Rights' for installation.

Then I head to the User Account section and notice that I am still the administrator, although the password has been removed! Furthermore, I set the password, and after few days back when I again log in to my system, the password is removed, and a new game is installed.

Now at this point I am very angry; my brother has been using some kind of 'command prompt' based software (I noticed one day) to reset or remove the administrative password.
 I cannot keep him away from the system since I am away for work most of the times, and also cannot remove his account, for it's for his use too. I just don't want any such 'theft access' to my system.

Anyone has any idea, what he might be doing and how this can be resolved by some settings or so?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me that your younger brother has outsmarted you. 
I guess I know what he is doing if a command prompt window is involved. I also did it once to break into my school Server when the school lost its password. **It is done through the recovery console command prompt and Windows cmd**. 
Follow these steps:

1.Burn Windows 7 image to a USB stick and boot with it.
 2. Instead of installing Windows 7 select ***Repair this Computer***.
 3. From the recovery options menu select command prompt.
 4. Run the following commands:
      1. `C:` (this should be the drive letter of your current Windows 7 installation)
       2. `cd Windows/system32/`
       3. `rename utilman.exe utilman.bak`
       4. `rename cmd.exe utilman.exe`
5. Now exit the recovery console and boot to your Windows 7.
6. On the logon screen press`Win + U`
7. This will open the command prompt window instead of the utility manager.
8. Now type`netusr`. This will list all the users on your Windows 7.
9. Now type `netusr <username to reset password> <new password>` and press enter.
Your password for the selected user will now be reset. 
10. Login to the altered user account with the new password. 
But remember to go back to the recovery console command prompt and revert the filenames back to original i.e. utilman.exe--> cmd.exe, utilman.bak--> utilman.exe.

This is the safest method involving a command line interface to reset password. OR you may try interrogating your brother.

Comment: I did the same at university...